# cancel zooming in map control Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am working with map control in my Windows Phone application. After I have set route between two points, map control automaticaly zoom in. How can I implement not zoom in after seting a rote?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that you can't.

The map control automatically adjusts zoom levels when it pans and moves around and I haven't found a way around this other than keeping track of the original zoom level and resetting it after the control does its thing.

Answer (score 1):

You should just disable the map control, like this:

```
map1.IsEnabled = false;
```